# I want to show the column items from an existing sqlite database into an autocompletetextview using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-asynctask

This is my `getall()` method which is in `DataBaseHelper` Class

```
public ArrayList<String> getAll(){
        ArrayList<String> listUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c;

        try {
            c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM bank"  , null);
            if(c == null) return null;

            String name;
            c.moveToFirst();
            do {
                name = c.getString(1);
                listUsers.add(name);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("blushmaq", e.getMessage());
        }

        db.close();

        return listUsers;
    }
```

This is my other class where I want to populate the records from the `getall()` method which is in `DataBaseHelper`

```
public class BankInfo extends ActionBarActivity {


    private Toolbar toolbar;
    Button searchButton;
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    TextView sample;
    AutoCompleteTextView t1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bank_info);

        sample = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextView);
        searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new DBOperations().execute();
            }
        });

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        DBOperations.execute(true);
        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private class DBOperations extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            return params[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            ArrayList<String> brands = myDbHelper.getAll();
            t1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.bank_name);
            if(brands != null){
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(BankInfo.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,brands);
                t1.setThreshold(1);
                t1.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            sample.setText(s);
            myDbHelper.close();
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the error  `ArrayIndexOutofBoundException Length=0 Index=0`

Comment: is your myDbHelper.getAll() return some values?

Comment: The full stack trace would help.

Comment: @PramodWaghmare its actually not storing anything. Debugging shows value 0.

Comment: @JornBuitink Stack trace shows the table name does not exist.

Comment: go through my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reinstall the app.

Reason is,

1. You create project and add code for database.

2.Install app .

3.again make any changes in database

at this point database not updated.

**Do this.**

Just use the onUpgrade (as an override) method, and you can put your database upgrades there. this way, none of the existing data will be blown away when the application has already been installed.

And make sure you don't drop the table as you're currently doing on:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bank");
```

If you don't want to follow this.

**Uninstall app and again install**

Refer [How to Update Database changes to already Installed Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235188/how-to-update-database-changes-to-already-installed-application)

Comment: The thing is..I'm not making any changes to the database. I just want to read records from it and display.The database is already created. My app just want to access and display its content.

Comment: Uninstall app then install again

Answer (score 0):

It seems your data base does not have any value or you did not declair any array properly.
And check condition  "if(brands != null) " with the brand.size()>0 also .

Comment: tried with brand.size()>0, it goes not give any error but still no suggestions are shown in edittext.

Comment: 1) did you receive any value in brand? if not then first insert value in sqlite DB then try. if db is empty then it shows nothing.

Comment: I don't know how to check for the contents of brand. Could you help me?
And the database is already containing the records. It's not empty.

Comment: brands is not receiving any value. I did a system.out.println.
And i'm getting error that the table does not exist.

Comment: Then first insert desired value in DB .and then retrive value from db

Comment: ok now the database connection is working. I checked the data from db into a textview. Now how to put it on autocompletetextview